# Angular Rails Karma testing Controller with factory (with backend api calls) dependency

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I have a `projectFactory`:

```
@app.factory "projectFactory", ['$http', ($http) ->
  factory = {}

  factory.loadProject = (projectId) ->
    $http.get( endpoint(projectId) )
```

(`endpoint` is a method that generates the backend api url)

I then have a `projectCtrl` that is dependent on that factory:

```
@app.controller 'ProjectCtrl', ['$scope','$routeParams', 'projectFactory', ($scope, $routeParams, projectFactory) ->

    $scope.projectId = $routeParams.projectId

    $scope.loadProject = (projectId) ->
      projectFactory.loadProject(projectId)
      .success((data)->$scope.project = data.project)
```

I then have my `project_control_spec` test:

```
'use strict'
describe "ProjectCtrl", ->

  beforeEach module 'app'

  ProjectCtrl = {}
  $scope = {}
  projectFactory = {}

  beforeEach ->
     module($provide) ->
       $provide.factory "projectFactory", projectFactory

     module inject($controller, $rootScope) ->
       $scope = $rootScope.$new()
       ProjectCtrl = $controller 'ProjectCtrl', {
         $scope : $scope,
         $routeParams: {projectId: 1},
       }

  it "should instantiate a PC", ->
    expect(ProjectCtrl).toBeDefined()

  it "should have access to the projectId via the routeParams", ->
    expect($scope.projectId).toEqual(1)

  it "should have access to projectFactory", ->
    expect($scope.projectFactory).toBeDefined()

  it "should create $scope.project when calling loadProject", ->
    expect($scope.project).toBeUndefined();
    expect($scope.loadProject(1)).toBe(1)
    expect($scope.project).toEqual({//a project object})
```

I am getting the error `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $provide`, when trying to require my projectFactory

Answer (score 0):

You cannot inject $provide on line `module inject($controller, $rootScope,  $provide) ->`. It is also not used or needed in any case.

You should also test this case with [$httpBackend](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend). Check the first example.

Comment: That was an accident, I had removed that injection in my code and it still gave the same error of not being able to find `$provide` from this line `module($provide) ->
       $provide.factory "projectFactory", projectFactory
`

Comment: @kittyminky Is coffeescript parsed right in that case, maybe you need to write

`module ($provide) -> $provide.factory "projectFactory", projectFactory` or

`module(($provide) -> $provide.factory "projectFactory", projectFactory)`

Answer (score 0):

What if you try this ?
(It is in javascript, sorry I can't write coffee yet)

```
beforeEach( inject (function( $injector ){
  $provide = $injector.get('$provide');
  // ...
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with CoffeeScript, but this is how I would do it in plain old JS:

```
var projectFactory = {};

beforeEach(function () {
  module('app', function ($provide) {
    $provide.factory('projectFactory', projectFactory);
  });
});
```

When taking some of your code and running it through a Coffee to JS interpreter, I get the following result:

```
describe("ProjectCtrl", function() {

  var $scope, ProjectCtrl, projectFactory;

  beforeEach(module('app'));

  ProjectCtrl = {};
  $scope = {};
  projectFactory = {};

  beforeEach(function() {
    module($provide)(function() {
      $provide.factory("projectFactory", projectFactory);
    });
  });

});
```

Basically you're trying to load a second module called `$provide`, when what you actually want to do is open up a config block for the first module (`app`) and **inject** `$provide` into the configuration block.

If you were using angular.module for your actual implementation of `app`, it'd look something like this:

```
angular.module('app', []).config(function ($provide) {

  $provide.value('..', {});
  $provide.constant('...', {});

  /** and so on **/

});
```

Whereas in your specs when using `angular-mocks`, a config block gets set like this:

```
module('app', function ($provide) {
  $provide.value('..', {});

  /** and so on **/
});
```

I hope that helps. I'm not sure how you would actually write this in CoffeeScript, but I'm sure you can figure that one out. When taking the result of the Coffee to JS interpreter of your code, I received the same result - there is no variable `$provide`.